# Javascript not working in Chrome/Firefox but ok in Safari

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

I'm working on a image overlay section in my website. Three images are in elements which are stacked and revealed one at a time by resizing the elements horizontally using the scrollbar position. It works perfectly in Safari but not in Chrome/Firefox.

I have run the code through the w3c validator and fixed all issues but I still have the same problem...works in safari but not in Chrome/Firefox.

I would really appreciate it if someone could take a look at the code for me below.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

---

```js
var xyz;
var slide1Width = $("#slide1").width();

var slide2Width = $("#slide2").width();
var slide3Width = $("#slide3").width();
var counter = 0;

$(document).ready(function(e) {

  /////////Slide scroll-resize activation/////////
  $(window).scroll(function(e) {

    var slide1Height = $("#slide1").height();


    xyz = $("body").scrollTop();
    $("#inputs").text(xyz);

    //When slide1 scroll-resize is enabled
    if (xyz <= slide1Width && xyz >= 50) {
      $("#slide2").css({
        "width": xyz
      });
    };

    //When slide2 scroll-resize is enabled
    if (xyz >= slide1Width * 2 + 25 && xyz <= slide1Width * 3) {
      $("#slide3").css({
        "width": xyz - slide1Width * 2
      });
    };

    var video = document.getElementById("video");
    video.currentTime = (xyz - slide1Width) / 55;

    if (xyz >= slide1Width && xyz < slide1Width * 2) {
      $("#video").css({
        "visibility": "visible"
      });
    } else {
      $("#video").css({
        "visibility": "hidden"
      });
    };

    $("#video").height($("#slide1").height());
    /*$("#video").width($("#slide1").width());*/

  });



});

window.onload = function(e) {




  var x = $("#slide1").width();
  var y = $("#slide1").innerHeight();



  $("#slide2").resizable({
    containment: "parent",
    minWidth: 50,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $("body").scrollTop($(this).width());
    }
  });

  $("#slide2").css({

    "height": y,
    "width": 50

  });

  $("#slide3").resizable({
    containment: "parent",
    minWidth: 25,
    stop: function(event, ui) {
      $("body").scrollTop($(this).width() + x);

    }
  });

  $("#slide3").css({

    "height": y,
    "width": 25

  });

  ///////////Slide 3 click behaviour////////////

  //Single click//

  $("#slide3").click(function(e) {
    $("body").scrollTop($("#slide1").width() * 2 + $(this).width());
  });

  //Double click//

  $("#slide3").dblclick(function(e) {
    $("body").scrollTop($("#slide2").width());
  });


  ///////////Slide 2 click behaviour////////////

  //Single click//

  $("#slide2").click(function(e) {
    $("body").scrollTop($(this).width());



  });



};

$(window).resize(function() {

  var x = $("#slide1").width();
  var y = $("#slide1").innerHeight();
  var z = $("#slide2").width();
  var slide3width = $("#slide3").width();

  var result = z / x;
  var b = result * 100;
  var c = b.toString() + "%";

  var result3 = slide3width / x;
  var slide3percentInt = result3 * 100;
  var slide3percentString = slide3percentInt.toString() + "%";



  $("#slide2").css({
    "height": y,
    "width": c

  });

  $("#slide2").resizable({
    minWidth: 50,
    containment: "parent"

  });

  $("#slide3").css({
    "height": y,
    "width": slide3percentString

  });

  $("#slide3").resizable({
    minWidth: 25,
    containment: "parent"

  });


});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: black;
  height: 5000px;
}

#box1 {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}

#wrapper {
  position: fixed;
  width: 80%;
  height: auto;
  margin: auto;
  left: 10%;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}

#slide1 {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 1;
}

#slide2 {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("WESetBW.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 2;
}

#slide3 {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  background-image: url("WESetViz.svg");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 4;
}

#video {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin: 0;
  border: none;
  z-index: 3;
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#inputs {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: white;
  color: red;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">

    <div id="box1">
    </div>

    <div id="slide1">
      <img src="WESet-photo.svg" alt="World's End set" />

    </div>

    <div id="slide2">
    </div>

    <div id="slide3">
    </div>

    <video id="video">
        <source src="WEsetOriginalVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
     </video>

  </div>
  <div id="inputs">

  </div>

  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'd get a better response if you created a proper demo. Use the snippet tool in the editor, or set it up at http://jsfiddle.net, for example.

Comment: Your HTML does not contain anything that law except some JavaScript and css includes and a heading element, how is one expected to answer your question based on this alone?

Comment: Please edit the snippet to reproduce your issue. You cna use dummy images from https://dummyimage.com/ to mimic images if you don't want to show yours.

Comment: At first glance, you should have `slide1width` and all of that code included inside your `document.ready` function. As it stands, those lines may be running before those elements have loaded, and therefore the width values will be wrong.

Comment: Thanks, jmcgriz. I found the answer finally though many search engine searches. In the end calling scrollTop on the 'document' worked in all browser's as apposed to calling it on the 'body' which only worked in Safari: